# Change the shape of an outline in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Am running Office Professional Plus 2013 on Windows 7.

Have a matrix as depicted in the following image: [image: taxon matrix]

Full matrix data is found in this [Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1riqSA_lGE4qiVmRxDr-m1hGXyUXc67qmL_Jzd7NAJsA/edit?usp=sharing). There are two tabs - generic terms and specific terms.

Matrix is used to classify `items` - such as specific plants. There are `items` assigned to this matrix, but they are not shown to reduce complexity.

The matrix is a normalized matrix, meaning that the columns are fixed - there is place in the matrix for all possible values. But in many cases there is no value (a NULL value) for a column. For example, the genus on row 8 is defined by `kingdom : subkingdom : division : class : order : family : genus`.

The columns `subdivision`, `subclass`, `superorder`, `suborder` and `family` are not used to define that specific genus. In contrast, the `genus` on row 14 is defined by `subdivision`.

Using symbols, the normalized matrix looks as follows:
[image: symbolic matrix]

The goal is create a de-normalized matrix - to reshape the matrix where a column no longer has a meaning, but is just a level in the outline. The general approach is to delete a NULL cell and - on the next line(s) - move its dependent "children" left.

The manual process would be:

1. Delete D5 and move `Class` left.
2. Delete E6 and move `Order` left.
3. Repeat ad nauseam.

The de-normalized matrix would look like this:

[image]

Fortunately, symbols in the first three columns are never NULL (C - constant) - we can reference them, but do not need to move them. But the position of a symbol in all other columns is variable (V - variable), depending on which nulls have been deleted.

There is one wrinkle. There are instances where an `item` (implied but not shown) is not mapped to `genus`. Instead, the `item` is mapped to a broader terms such as `family`. Row 15 is an example where `family` is the terminal node; `genus` is **not** used to define this `item`.

**How to create an Excel formula or script that:**

1. deletes a NULL position
2. on the row with the deleted NULL position, moves the term left
3. on the next row(s) that are related to the parent cell, move the term(s) to the left?

If it is easier to work with names (`division`, `subdivision`, `class`, etc.) than with symbols, that's OK. The Google spreadsheet provides the generic term and the specific term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample output of my formula based solution:

[image]

There are 2 helper columns (`M`, `N`).

Formula in `M2` (calculates current item's position in row), fill the column with it:

```
=MATCH("*",A2:L2,0)
```

Formula in `N2` (calculate new item's position in row), fill the column with it:

```
=IF(M2-M1>0,N1+1,IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($M$1:M1=M2),$N$1:N1),M2))
```

Formula in O2 simply places the item in right column, fill entire range with it:

```
=IF($N2=O$1,INDEX($A2:$L2,1,$M2),"")
```

It takes some time to calculate all rows, but I think it produces the desired output.

**EDIT:**

I think I found a bug in my solution, the formula in `N2` should be:

```
=IF(M2-M1>0,N1+1,LOOKUP(2,1/($M$1:M1<M2),$N$1:N1)+1)
```

I didn't notice it earlier, because it affects row `2468` (`Amborellanae`).

Comment: looks promising - gimme a moment to see if I can replicate your approach.

Comment: brilliant; works perfectly. There's a line in the movie `Good Will Hunting` when the professor stands before the chalk board solution and says to his class (para-phrasing) "Unmasks yourself." It's a variation from the movie `Butch Cassidy and the Sundance Kid` when Butch (Paul Newman) says to Sundance (Robert Redford) `Who are those guys ..." Your solutions are tutorials on how to use Excel.

Comment: @JayGray thanks for kind words, but I found a bug and updated the answer